# Sage command :To find a polynomial using lagrange interpolation over finite Ring

Tags: sagemath

how  to initialize  lagrange_polynomial command for Finite Ring . It works for Finite  Field,Z and Q . I tried for Ring with finite order,  for me its shows ERROR.here is the  code:

```
R = PolynomialRing(Zmod(8), 'x')
R.lagrange_polynomial([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(7,0),(0,1)])
```

It shows " Attribute Error, Couldn't use Lagrange here".
don't know Why . Can anyone help me to fix the  Error. Thank you  in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE! For future reference, these kinds of sage questions might get answered more quickly at [ask.sagemath.org](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/), but since you're here I'll happily answer it ^_^.

The issue is that [lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) only works over a field, which $\mathbb{Z}/8$ notably isn't. When we do lagrange interpolation we have to *divide*. For instance, say you want to find a line connecting $(1,1)$ and $(3,1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/8$. Then the method outputs the polynomial

$$
\frac{x-1}{3-1} + \frac{x-3}{1-3} = \frac{x-1}{2} - \frac{x-3}{2}
$$

of course, we can't invert $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/8$!

This is a toy example (obviously the constant $1$ polynomial interpolates these two points) but it showcases the problems with lagrange interpolation over rings that aren't integral domains.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you!   Finite Ring can have  zero divisors.for example in Z4  2*2=4 which is congruent to 0 mod 4 .(product of two non zero elements can be zero).that's why we cant apply Lagrange interpolation in Ring . In this situation we get ZeroDivisionrError!  is my  understanding crt?

Comment: Yes! That's basically the idea ^_^